# Click a button on a Browser native Javascript pop up alert window Selenium/C#

Tags: javascript, c#, selenium

There is a *Delete* button on the form, once it gets clicked, a Browser native pop up alert window is asking to confirm the action. How can I click on *OK* since I can't see any html of that window?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To click OK on an alert:

```
driver.SwitchTo().Alert().Accept();
```

Answer (score 1):

> `window.confirm()` returns `Boolean` value.

`true` if `OK` is clicked and `false` if `Cancel` is clicked.

```js
console.log(window.confirm());
```